# Android custom view setShadowLayer onDraw recursive call

Tags: android

I define custom line Chart view, I want draw shadowLayer

```
 mFoldLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 mFoldLinePaint.setPathEffect(null);
 canvas.drawPath(mPath, mFoldLinePaint);
 mFoldLinePaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(line.getPoint(0).fLineX, line.getPoint(0).fLineY, line.getPoint(line.getSize() - 1).fLineX, line.getPoint(line.getSize() - 1).fLineY, mFoldLineGradientLeftColor, mFoldLineGradientRightColor, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
 setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
 mFoldLinePaint.setShadowLayer(5, 5, -5, Color.BLACK);
```

then I get problems

1.onDraw recursive call

2.Black color not work（shadow Layer work）
any one help me?

Comment: I found setShader cause black color not work

Comment: I found I remove this code  setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); onDraw() method just call one time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.remove this code setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); from custom view
add mView.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); in activity or fragment

2.Black color not work（shadow Layer work）
drawPath two time

```
    mFoldLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mFoldLinePaint.setPathEffect(null);
    mFoldLinePaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(line.getPoint(0).fLineX, line.getPoint(0).fLineY, line.getPoint(line.getSize() - 1).fLineX, line.getPoint(line.getSize() - 1).fLineY, mFoldLineGradientLeftColor, 
    mFoldLineGradientRightColor, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

    mFoldLinePaintVice.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mFoldLinePaintVice.setPathEffect(null);
    mFoldLinePaintVice.setShadowLayer(5, 5, -5, Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mFoldLinePaintVice);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mFoldLinePaint);
```